# How to merge multiple mp3 files with silence on between?

Tags: python, glob, pydub

When I try to merge multiple .mp3 files from a folder using `pydub` and `glob` to iterate over the files I get the following error.

```py
from pydub import AudioSegment
from os import getcwd
import glob

cwd = (getcwd()).replace(chr(92), '/')
export_path = f'{cwd}/result.mp3'

MP3_FILES = glob.glob(pathname=f'{cwd}/*.mp3', recursive=True)
silence = AudioSegment.silent(duration=15000)
count, lenght = 0, len(MP3_FILES)

for n, mp3_file in enumerate(MP3_FILES):
    mp3_file = mp3_file.replace(chr(92), '/')
    count += 1
    if count == 1:
        print(n, mp3_file)
        audio1 = AudioSegment.from_mp3(mp3_file)
    elif count == 2:
        audio2 = AudioSegment.from_mp3(mp3_file)
    elif count == 3:
        res = audio1 + silence + audio2
        print('Merging')
        count = 0
    if n+1 == lenght:
        res.export(export_path, format='mp3')
        print('\ndone!')
```

---

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:** one audio file with silence between the orinal audios.

```
AUDIO_RESULT: audio1 silence audio2 silence audio3...
```

---

**Traceback:**

```
[mp3 @ 0000021b440ec740] Failed to read frame size: Could not seek to 1026.
C:\Users\Acer\Documents\1 file.mp3: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Please post your error output as text!

Comment: @KlausD. updated

Comment: Looks like a bad MP3 - maybe its some other format with the wrong extension

Comment: @rep_movsd If I try to input one by one mp3 will work, but the idea is iterare to get them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says - `Invalid argument` which might be caused by space used in file path.

If you pass your file/folder path using command line, the path string should be passed inside a **quotation**("")

```
"C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Upwork\Shashank Rai\mp3 segmented delay\1 speech.mp3"
```

However, in Windows OS sometimes `C:\` creates problem because one single `\` is used for special character. Would you please test with double `\\` ?

`"C:\\Users\\Acer\\..."`

EDIT 1:
would you please test this -

```
from pathlib import Path 

cwd = Path.cwd()
MP3_FILES = list(cwd.rglob('*.mp3'))
...
...
```

Comment: I test it with `C:/.../` using `(cwd()).replace(chr(92), '/')`, however I don't know pass \\ to os.cwd()

Comment: as I said before, it worked if I use  `sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(f"{cwd}/file.mp3")`

Comment: thank you. I have edited my answer. Would you please try `EDIT 1` section?

Comment: I will mark this as the answer, however somehow in the process the mp3 files were corrupted, downloading them again and running the script it seems to work fine